# How can you reliably survive Uranium?

Tags: go-beryllium

I'm struggling to find a way to reliably pass Uranium in [Go Beryllium](http://cokane.com/games/beryllium/), Hard. I'd rather not use the shield because it can easily make matters worse, even when played to the beat.

I have, for example, found that at the start there is a short-lived safe spot at the top, right next to it that nevertheless helps me get by the first wave of... erm... radiation?

When I *do* pass it with enough energy, I don't have a lot of trouble getting at least at the end of stage three -- too many of my attempts, however, finish there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvzwN5xSw58#t=1m10s), you can see NeoCyst's high score run. He gets past the Uranium element without getting hit or using the shield.

It seems like his strategy consists of two parts:

- He tries to stay close below of and centered with the Uranium, while going through the walls of bullets. He usually does this switching between going to the right in parallel to the walls consisting of 3-5 shots while they open up, then using the space in between the 'wings' to go left again and move back to his spot in the middle below the Uranium.
- Flying right over the Uranium and finishing it when it is safe.

The most trouble are really the Hydrogen and Helium elements flying around while you're trying to deal with the Uranium. NeoCyst takes care of them pretty elegantly.

Comment: By the way, bosses deplete on their own in this game -- no need to shoot it. You _are_ supposed to get hurt by the collision, however... are you not?

Comment: Read the comment below the video. Apparently, they drop more quarks and do no final 'blow' if you kill them before the time runs out. However, I can not see that in the video (it looks like a timeout death, but there are no final shots.)